# How to set permissions on one page only in site?

Tags: permissions

I have created a site within sharepoint portal. I have two pages that only one user can access it. How do I add permissions for this page only?

Comment: Updating this question for 2019. There doesn't seem to be a way to break permissions for a page from the parent site.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set permissions on a single page within a site then:

In Site Content go to the Site Pages library.
Then set the permissions on a page level the same way you would set permissions on a document, folder or site.

i.e 
Click on the ellipses next to the page name and Share it with only one person.

Answer (score 1):

Break permissions from top site.

Then either make a new SP group and add a user to the group

or

Invite a user to the page and give him permissions.

First method is much easier to maintain in the long run.

Worth remembering: 
The Top level admin can read this page and if you are using SharePoint online the global admin will still be able to read everything on the page. So if the page has to be hidden from everybody the admins will still be able to read.

Comment: If I broke permissions from top site, I won't have access to the site anymore as I am not an admin on the sharepoint portal. I just want to remove all users permission on that specific page and allow only one user to access it.

Comment: hmm... well you can certainly invite a person to the site them and remove everybody else. However Administrators will still be able to see that page. If it is some secret HR stuff then it might not be a good idea for admins to have insight. Also depending what group you belong to if you remove the group you will loose permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is no content being dropped into your page (via web part), you will also need to control permissions of the content. Or people will be able to see the content via the "`View All Content`" or by simply typing "`/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx`" in their address bar. Oddly, people often are surprised, after dropping content with unique permissions into a page, that only the people who have access to that content can see that page. Everyone else will receive an "access denied" page. Hope that helps.