# Manage page permissions without going to site contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, sitepages, item-level-permissions

In the past, if we browsed to a page, we could go into that page's permissions by selecting **Page** > **Page Permissions**.

[image]

I would suppose that something similar would be available in Office 365 but I **cannot seem to find anything related to page permissions**, while located on the page itself. I can see **Page Details** and other options but nothing to check the permissions and change them.

[image]

I am therefore forced to go into **Site contents**, enter the **Site Pages** library, find my way into the page I want and then **3 dots** > **Manage access**.

If there a way to go to the permissions of a page that I am too blind to see, or do I have to go all the way around every time I need to do this?

**Related**:

[How to set permissions on one page only in site?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/how-to-set-permissions-on-one-page-only-in-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct option available on the page itself for modifying permissions for pages in modern experience like it was available in classic experience.

So, you have to go through the site pages library only to change the permissions for individual pages.

Comment: alright. fingers crossed for some developments on this

Answer (score 0):

You can only use manage access to the page you want to edit permissions in the page library.

1. Enter the page library
2. Select the page you want to edit permissions, click the three dots, select Manage access--> Advanced settings, and enter the permission interface.
3. Just set the permission you want.
   [image]

Comment: I think we already established that. if you see the info in my post